# incorrect Connection URL - DB2 11.1 and Weblogic 12c

Tags: db2, weblogic12c

I have deployed Java application in Weblogic 12c. Created Datasource with Driver Class Name as `com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource`

When i try to get Connection URL from the application, weblogic returns `jdbc:db2:TESTDB`, i.e, without serverName and Port Number

But when i use `com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver` as Driver Class Name in datasource, i get connection URL with serverName and Port Number i.e., `jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/TESTDB`

How to get correct URL using `com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource` as Driver Class Name?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Whose jdbc driver for Db2 are you using?  Oracle supplies a Type-4 jdbc driver for Db2 with class weblogic.jdbcx.db2.DB2DataSource  for XA distributed transactions with its own URL format.  IBM's driver has different class name and URL format.

Comment: I'm using db2jcc.jar and db2jcc4.jar, that is supplied by IBM. Moreover, i have provided URL under Connection pool as jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/TESTDB. why system is not picking and returning the same ?

Comment: How URL is formed when Connection.getMetaData().getURL() is called ?